# Spark - aggregate and sum children with parent records

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, dataset, aggregation

I work with data that has a structure of a tree. Each parent can have multiple children. Parent has no information about a children, but each child knows its parent. Additionally each child knows its full path - which is a string of concatenated parent identifiers, so each record knows its level in the tree. This record has a structure:

```
id  | parent_id | path
--- + --------- + ------
11  | 1         | 1-11
12  | 1         | 1-12
121 | 12        | 1-12-121
```

And now I have to read the table, group by id and sum a column `value` of type bigint. And the most important fact is only the leafs - elements without children - has specified value and each parent has to be a sum of all its children value. Initially all parents have a value equal to 0.

Before grouping:

```
Root
| - Parent 1 (value = 0)
| - - Child 11 (value = 1)
| - - Child 12 (value = 1)
| - - Parent 13 (value = 0)
| - - - Child 131 (value = 2)
| - - - Child 132 (value = 1)
| - Parent 2 (value = 0)
| - - Child 21 (value = 2)
| - - Child 22 (value = 1)
```

Result of grouping:

```
Root
| - Parent 1 (value = 5 (1 + 1 + 3))
| - - Child 11 (value = 1)
| - - Child 12 (value = 1)
| - - Parent 13 (value = 3 (2 + 1))
| - - - Child 131 (value = 2)
| - - - Child 132 (value = 1)
| - Parent 2 (value = 3 (2 + 1))
| - - Child 21 (value = 2)
| - - Child 22 (value = 1)
```

And really important requirement: I cannot collect this data and group in memory, because the dataset is really huge therefore I have to do it using a dataset or a dataframe.

Comment: do you have id 1, id 2 as a records in your table? if so, what are it's parent ids and paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are only interested in the sum of values for each node. In that case, you just have to look at each time a node appears in one of the paths, and add all such values for the corresponding node. a spark version would be:

```scala
scala> val df = spark.sql(s"""
  select
    col1 as id,
    col2 as parent_id,
    col3 as path,
    col4 as value
  from values
    (11, 1, "1-11", 1),
    (12, 1, "1-12", 1),
    (13, 1, "1-13", 0),
    (131, 13, "1-13-131", 2),
    (132, 13, "1-13-132", 1)
""")


scala> (df
 .withColumn("path_arr", split(col("path"), "-"))
 .select($"value", explode($"path_arr").as("node"))
 .groupBy("node")
 .sum()
 .orderBy($"node")
).show
```

which yields:

```
+----+----------+
|node|sum(value)|
+----+----------+
|   1|         5|
|  11|         1|
|  12|         1|
|  13|         3|
| 131|         2|
| 132|         1|
+----+----------+
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you !